# including thread interupts listening through sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I've writting a server using the help of Microsoft MSDN...

It works perfectly with my client, connects and everything, but when I add -

```
#include <thread>
```

simply this line to my project, it makes the server stop working (allways getting invalid socket when binding / listening)...

this is my code :

```
SOCKET Connect_To_Client()
{
     // Initialize Winsock.
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

int count = 0;
while (iResult != NO_ERROR) 
{
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    count++;

    if (count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "WSA Startup failed!", "ERROR", MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }


}

// Create a SOCKET for listening for incoming connection requests.
SOCKET ListenSocket;
ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

count = 0;
while (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    count++;

    if (count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error in Listening Socket!", "ERROR", MB_OK);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
}

//ADDR
sockaddr_in service;
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(DEFAULT_IP);
service.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

count = 0;
bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & service, sizeof (service));

// Listen for incoming connection requests on the created socket
count = 0;
cout << "Listening..." << endl;
while (listen(ListenSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    count++;

    if (count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error listening!", "ERROR", MB_OK);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
}

SOCKET AcceptSocket; // Create a SOCKET for accepting incoming requests.

// Accept the connection.
AcceptSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

count = 0;
while(AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    AcceptSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    count++;

    if (count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error Connecting", "ERROR", MB_OK);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
}

cout << "Connected!" << endl;
return AcceptSocket;
}
```

If I have the `#include <thread>` it doesnt work (invalid socket), and if I dont, it works perfectly..
What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should move the WSAStartup() call to a different place so it only happens once. And if it fails there is no point in repeating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in `<thread>` that should be affecting the winsock API in any way.  But just in case, you need to either precompile your code and look at the precompiler's output, or just step through your code with a debugger, and make sure all of your variables and function parameters have the correct values you are expecting.

Comment: Why there is a different, if when I remove the line, all the values are correct (ALLWAYS), and when I add the line, it doesnt?

Comment: Like I said, you need to either 1) precompile your code with and without `<thread>` present and see if anything is different, or 2) debug your code at runtime and see what is actually happening in each function call.  As your code currently stands, `<thread>` should not be affecting it, which suggests that `<thread>` is defining something unexpected, such as with a `#define` that happens to use the same name as something you are using.

Comment: How can I precompile it, or debug it at runtime?

Comment: C++ is a two-stage compiled language. Code is preprocessed to resolve macros and such, then that preprocessed output is compiled and linked to make the final executable. Most C++ compilers/IDEs have an option to invoke the preprocessor manually and save the output to a file. And most C++ compilers/IDEs have a debugger to debug compiled executables. Check the capabilities of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

is required for sockets.  The

```
#include <thread>
```

is used for the new threading support in C++11 and I believe it is only supported in VC13 or maybe VC12.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, and I've allways used  ` #include <thread> `  before, just not with sockets at the same project...